# Get string between two sets of characters in shell

Tags: bash, sed

I pipe the following string `"version": "1.0.0",` to `sed` and I'm trying to get `1.0.0` out of it. I want to get it by the rule: get string between `: "` and `",`.

I've been trying the following:

```
sed -e '/:\ \"/,/\ ",/p'
sed -e 's/:\ \"\(.*\)\",/\1/'
```

The first one does nothing and the last one returns `"version"1.0.0`, which is close, but no cigar. What am I missing?

Comment: Obviously we don't know where your original string came from but if it was part of a JSON file, then you could just use `jq -r .version file.json`

Comment: @TomFenech, my bad. I updated my post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match complete input by using `.*` on either side of your search pattern to be able to replace full line with just the captured group's back-reference.

This `sed` should work:

```
s='"version": "1.0.0",'

sed 's/.*: "\([^"]*\)",.*/\1/' <<< "$s"    
1.0.0
```

Or even this one:

```
sed 's/.*: "\(.*\)",.*/\1/' <<< "$s"
1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using grep with lookahead/lookbehind:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=: ")[^"]*(?=")' <<< '"version": "1.0.0",'
1.0.0
```

or shorter, using `\K` to exclude `: "` from the matched string:

```
$ grep -oP ': "\K[^"]+' <<< '"version": "1.0.0",'
1.0.0
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm on OS X and the `-P` option for `grep` isn't available.